# Using Python and Beautiful Soup to pickup texts on not a direct webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to do the following:

1. pickup texts on page (not the same as browser open)
2. handle multiple pages

The case is that:

I am trying to use Python and Beautifulsoup to pick up a list of Dutch
companies on the website http://www.fenex.nl.

I tried below keys however none of them worked out.

```
soup.find_all('span')
soup.find_all('a')
soup.find_all('td')
soup.find_all('tr')
soup.find_all("tr",{"class":"even"})
```

Then I found from the main page, tab "Vind een expediteur" then "Toon
alle leden", it leads to [this member page](http://www.fenex.nl/over-fenex/ledenlijst/zoekresultaat-ledenlijst). However actually when directly key in this web address, it doesn't go to the member list page.

So how can I pick up the list of members?

Another very important question is: The pages lasts to 45, and maybe in future it changes. How can I have the Python code know to pick them page by page?

Comment: http://www.fenex.nl/over-fenex/ledenlijst/zoekresultaat-ledenlijst I don't see any members on this page. Do you see them? Maybe I must authorize before see them?

Comment: thanks for the comment. the main site is http://www.fenex.nl. on the main site, click tab "Vind een expediteur" then "Toon alle leden", it leads to the members list page.

Comment: @MarkK itdxer's link is where you just directed him to go to. Are all the "Bedrijf"s members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe try create some robot for pages. `BeautifulSoap` is library for easy parsing of html text and thats all. If you want go page by page you must write it using `urllib`. This is simple example:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

url = "http://www.domain.com/page/path?page="
count_of_pages = 10

for page in xrange(1, count_of_pages):
    response = urllib.urlopen("%s%d" % (url, page))
    webPage = BeautifulSoup(webFile.read())

    # Parse page with great module BeaurifulSoap
```

But this code help you for normal loading pages. This page get data from AJAX. Look on this  page:

`http://www.fenex.nl/CMS/asynchronousrendering/CrmSearchResultFenexMemberCompanies/CrmSearchResultFenexMemberCompaniesByMemberCriteriaRenderControl.aspx?_=1384960662265&cid=9&pageNr=1&fenexSearchId=-214748364`

I you use chorme you can press `Ctrl + Shift + J`, Open tab `Network` and reload the page. You can see all requrest, and in this list you can find correct urls with data.

Comment: many thanks itdxer for teaching me to do multiple pages. this's great!

Comment: plus: AJAX is a new thing to me. glad to learn the way using Chrome to see the actual picture. but when i open the link, it gives a blank page withe words "Er zijn geen bedrijven gevonden met de opgegeven criteria." so i guess it changes every time.

Comment: Yes. This link has live time. You just need get correct rule for this link and describe you logic in python code before page opening.